# Undefined index: file in

Tags: php

I'm trying to fix the error `Undefined index: file in`.

Here's my code:

```
if (isset($_FILES['picture'])) {

}

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO events (title, text, picture) VALUES 
('".$_POST["title"]."','".$_POST["text"]."','".addslashes("" . $_FILES["file"] 
["name"])."')");

$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$tmp = (explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
$extension = end($tmp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . $_FILES["file"]["size"] . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

if (file_exists("../../images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "../images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "../images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
}
}
else
{
echo "Invalid file";
} 


mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: what is the error post here ?` undefined index...` and so on ??

Comment: First you check `$_FILES['picture']` and then you switch to `$_FILES['file']`. Is it intended?

Comment: Please format the code

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL Injections.

Comment: Your problem is that $_FILES["file"] is not set because $_FILES in your case does not contain the "file" index. To check if $_FILES contains anything, try var_dump($_FILES) in the beginning of your script and post the results.

Comment: Did you declare enctype property `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag?

Answer (score 1):

You should decide between

```
$_FILES['picture']
```

and

```
$_FILES['file']
```

This is probably where your error comes from.

Answer (score 0):

If your file input element name is file `<input type='file' name='file'>`

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {

    //code goes here

}
```